# Swift 3.0, Alamofire 4.0 Extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have read all the questions on this issue [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490839/alamofire-swift-3-0-extra-parameter-in-call) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879355/alamofire-error-after-swift-3-0-migration-extra-argument-in-call-request-me). I have the following code

```
let fullURL = God.getFullURL(apiURL: self.apiUrl)
        if (getOrPost == God.POST) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: .POST, AnyObject: self.postData?, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        } else if (getOrPost == God.GET) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method : .GET, Parameters: getData, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        }
```

My Swift and Xcode versions are

```
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)
```

My pod file is

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Buseeta' do
        pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'master'
end

pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'

pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

I get `Extra argument 'method' in call` error on both Alamofire request lines.

Dont go mark this question as duplicate without carefully checking. I have fixed the code exactly as per the duplicate questions.

**EDIT 1**

I tried after removing the headers, same issue on `.POST` and `.GET`

```
let fullURL = God.getFullURL(apiURL: self.apiUrl)
        if (getOrPost == God.POST) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: .POST, AnyObject: self.postData?, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        } else if (getOrPost == God.GET) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method : .GET, Parameters: getData?, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
if (getOrPost == God.POST) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: .post, parameters: self.postData?, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        } else if (getOrPost == God.GET) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method : .get, parameters: getData?, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        }
```

**EDIT 3**

I replaced with `method : HTTPMethod.get,` still no change. Same issue.

Comment: You should update the method type. They should be lowercase such as .post and .get

Comment: This is a duplicate, your code is not similar at all, as you have argument like "AnyObject"

Comment: tried both your recommendations friends. same issue.. no change

Comment: Try removing the leading `.` in `.JSONEncoding` in your EDIT 2.

Comment: And the `?` in `getData?` and `self.postData?`, that doesn't make any sense either

Comment: I removed the leading `.` and I guess it helped that parameter. But I am still stuck at `.post` and `.get` extra parameter issue. Do I need to import HTTPMethod or something ?

Comment: Try extracting all parameters to typed variables. If you've already fixed all problems described above, probably the `parameters` argument is not the expected type. Try `let parameters: [String: Any] = self.postData` (did you remember to remove the `?` here, right?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another function to upload data:

```
func upload(
    _ data: Data,
    to url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .post,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> UploadRequest
```

And parameters for GET request must be of type [String: Any]

Comment: Tried `Alamofire.upload(postData: Data, to: fullURL, method: HTTPMethod.post, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }` I get an error `Ambigious reference to member upload(_:to:method:headers)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your link, here is the new definition of the method request:

```
let fullURL = God.getFullURL(apiURL: self.apiUrl)
        if (getOrPost == God.POST) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: .post, parameters: self.postData?, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        } else if (getOrPost == God.GET) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method : .get, parameters: getData, encoding:.JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have removed the headers.. exactly the same issue. No change at all.

Comment: again. exactly same issue. i made the change. Infact XCode shows `Parameters` in autocomplete

Comment: Strange, because the method definition is this:

Alamofire.request(<#T##url: URLConvertible##URLConvertible#>, method: <#T##HTTPMethod#>, parameters: <#T##Parameters?#>, encoding: <#T##ParameterEncoding#>, headers: <#T##HTTPHeaders?#>)

Try to clean your build folder

Comment: yeah, did a clean up. same issue no change.

Comment: Still the damn `Extra argument method in call.`

Answer (score 0):

What I tried was

```
var postData    : Parameters?
var getData    : Parameters?
```

in the init, I initalized the postData like this

```
self.postData       = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

and

```
 if (getOrPost == God.POST) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: postData as Parameters?, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        } else if (getOrPost == God.GET) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: getData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

This compiles without errors :). I tried the `upload` recommendation by @cosmicman66

```
if (getOrPost == God.POST) {
            Alamofire.upload(postData!, to: fullURL, headers:nil).responseJSON { response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        } else if (getOrPost == God.GET) {
            Alamofire.request(fullURL, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: getData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
                self.responseData = response.result.value
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

This did not work. The request did not reach. I read somewhere that upload should not be used for POST.

Comment: Alamofire guys are not recommending `upload`. Unfortunately they are also not suggesting a solution. Seriously SUCKS..

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was passing an `NSDictionary` for `parameters` and not to mention the error message was misleading.

According to the documentation, the parameters of the request is of type [String: Any]. I got my issue fixed by doing so.

I’m on Xcode 8.3.1, 
Alamofire 4.4.0

This is the code that worked for me:

```
Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: requestParameters(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in

      print(response)
}
```

`requestUrl` is String, `requestParameters()` returns swift dictionary of type [String: Any]. And it is `JSONEncoding.default`, not `.JSONEncoding.default`

Refer this thread on GitHub for clarification:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same problem but by changing parameters type as [String : any] solve my problem

```
 let parameters : [String:any] = ["key":value]
```