# Incorrect argument label in call wtih AlamoFire Session Manager download

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, alamofire

AlamoFire's documentation:

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("pig.png")

    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}
```

My code:

```
    fileprivate let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = { ... 

    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(".mp4")
        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
```

...

```
        self.manager.download(urlString, to: destination) { response in
```

compile error:
[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136560/setting-alamofire-custom-destination-file-name-instead-of-using-suggesteddownloa

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is update the method.  You can try to autofill but its unreliable.  My guess is the method is this method (which defaults to GET):

```
self.manager.download(urlString, to: destination).response { 
    (response) in 
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: its in the docs for Alamofire 4: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

Comment: was this the solution?